# Why can an algebraic extension of a local field be written as a tower of finite extensions?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, local-field

Let $K$ be a local field and $L$ an algebraic extension of $K$.
I found a statement that $L$ can be written as 
$$
L = \bigcup_{n=0}^\infty L_n, 
$$
where $L_n$ are finite extensions of $K$ with $L_n \subseteq L_{n+1}$.
I could not find any reference for this but one can show it using the known statement that there are only finitely many extensions of $K$ of a fixed degree.
Does anyone know if it is possible to state a more elementary proof?

Comment: In case when $K$ has only countably many elements you can use the fact that $K[x]$ is countable. Thus, one obtains the algebraic closure by adjoining countably many elements (each give a finite extension) and implies the statement. This takes care of all the non-Archimedean local fields of characteristic zero (all finite extensions of the $p$-adic numbers). For the reals and complex numbers this is clear. Thus, we are left with non-Archimedean local fields of characteristic p. This I don't know how to deal with.

Comment: Indeed, if you can show that there are only countably many extensions of $K$ of a fixed degree, you are done. Take the union over all those elements in some fixed algebraic closure of $K$. Then this union will give you all of the algebraic closure. Now taking just the extensions that are in $L$ gives you $L$. However, I don't know how to prove that there are only finitely (note that also countably many would be enough to use the argument) extensions of $K$ of a fixed degree.

Comment: It is known that there are only finitely many extensions of a fixed degree, it follows for instance from the mass formular by Serre for totally ramified extensions. I wonder if there is an easier way to prove the tower property directly.

Comment: What do you call a "local field "? Suppose that the residue field k of the local field K has non zero characteristic. Then, for any finite galois extension L/K with group G, the inertia subgroup $G_0$ is solvable. If moreover k is finite, then G itself is solvable. See e.g. Serre's "Local Fields", chap.4, !2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$K$ is a completion of a global field $K'$. Every finite extension $E$ of $K$ can be obtained as a completion of a finite extension $E'$ of $K'$. This implies that there are only countably many finite extensions of $K$, as $K'$ and hence $K'[x]$ are countable. Every algebraic extension $L$ of $K$ is the directed union of all finitely generated subextensions $L=\bigcup E_i$. Since there are only countably many, we can choose an enumeration $(E_n)_{n \in \Bbb N}$ and then set $L_n=E_1E_2\dots E_n$.